# Set column value to user input, limit to date format

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to get a popup box to appear asking the user to input a date. I want to ensure only dates in the DD/MM/YYYY format can be uploaded.

The below code works, however it allows for any input type to be inserted:

```
Call RunSQL("UPDATE Summary " & _
    "SET " & _
    "Date_of_Report = [Enter the Report date in the following format DD/MM/YYYY, with the DD being the last day of the month] " & _
    " WHERE Date_of_Report IS NULL ")
```

I also want to include the name of the file that is being updated in the prompt I tried do the following (where FileNameSelected is a variable that will contain a different value each time), but get an error:

```
Call RunSQL("UPDATE Summary " & _
    "SET " & _
    "Date_of_Report = [Enter the Report date for the '" & FileNameSelected & "' file in the following format DD/MM/YYYY, with the DD beng the last day of the month] " & _
    " WHERE Date_of_Report IS NULL ")
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could tell me how to set parameters around the format and also include the value of the FileNameSelected variable in the prompt.

Also for VBA popup boxes I know you use & vbCrLf & _ to create a new line for he message box, how do I do this with a prompt?

Comment: Look at using a small pop-up form with a text box on instead of the input box. This will allow you to use the DatePicker, and also perform any validation before running the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I would validate your date. It would be a lot easier with MM/DD/YYYY format. With DD/MM you have to entirely deal with it  or you have a risk that Access mixes months and days.

```
Public Sub Test_date_prompt()


    Dim strInpput As String
    Dim dtConverted As Date
    Dim OK As Boolean
    Dim FileNameSelected As String

    On Error GoTo Err_handler

    OK = False


    FileNameSelected = "Anything for this example"

    strinput = InputBox("Enter the Report date for the '" & FileNameSelected & "' file in the following format DD/MM/YYYY, with the DD being the last day of the month", "Enter date")

    ' testing if user inputed 10 characters
    If Len(strinput) = 10 Then
        ' testing if / separators are at the right place
        If Mid(strinput, 3, 1) = "/" And Mid(strinput, 6, 1) = "/" Then
            ' testing if DD, MM, YYYY placeholders are all numeric
            If IsNumeric(Left(strinput, 2)) And IsNumeric(Mid(strinput, 4, 2)) And IsNumeric(Right(strinput, 4)) Then
                'looks good
                OK = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

    If Not OK Then
        ' not good, abording process
        MsgBox "You have not entered a valid date in DD/MM/YYYY format !", vbExclamation, "Abording"
        GoTo Exit_Sub
    End If

    ' Converting in date which ensure a valid date, otherwise an error will occur
    dtConverted = DateSerial(Right(strinput, 4), Mid(strinput, 4, 2), Left(strinput, 2))


    ' if your Date_of_report type is DATE, do :
'    Call RunSQL("UPDATE Summary " & _
        "SET " & _
        "Date_of_Report = #" & Format(dtConverted, "MM/DD/YYYY") & "# " & _
        " WHERE Date_of_Report IS NULL ")

    ' if your Date_of_report type is STRING (bad!), do :
 '   Call RunSQL("UPDATE Summary " & _
        "SET " & _
        "Date_of_Report = '" & Format(dtConverted, "DD/MM/YYYY") & "' " & _
        " WHERE Date_of_Report IS NULL ")



Exit_Sub:
    Exit Sub

Err_handler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Really appriciate it!